# How to append a value from column B to a list if value in column A meets requirements?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Below is my code. Essentially I'm trying to build a couple of lists based on the values in the dataframe, but the list indexes have to correspond to each other. I want to add the x values that meet a condition to one list, but also their corresponding y values to a different list.

Via the error message, it appears I can't access the y_column row value, but I'm not sure why. Any help is appreciated!

```
df = customer_codes
x_column = 'X'
y_column = 'Y'
num_intervals = 10

maximum = df[x_column].max()
interval = maximum/num_intervals
intervals = []
i = 0

while i <= num_intervals:
    value = int(i * interval)
    intervals.append(value)
    i = i+1

for interval in intervals:
  for row in df[x_column]:
    if row >= interval:
          x_values.append(row)
          y_values.append(df[y_column][row])
```

This is the error I encounter:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-61-9e06679fdb72> in <module>()
     21     if row >= interval:
     22           x_values.append(row)
---> 23           y_values.append(df[y_column][row])

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_value(self, series, key)
   4728         k = self._convert_scalar_indexer(k, kind="getitem")
   4729         try:
-> 4730             return self._engine.get_value(s, k, tz=getattr(series.dtype, "tz", None))
   4731         except KeyError as e1:
   4732             if len(self) > 0 and (self.holds_integer() or self.is_boolean()):

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 291061
```

Comment: The error says that `row=291061` and that `df['Y'][291061]` doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

(Pandas has many functions that make the things you want to do easier. In this answer I only looked at the posted python code.)

The main problem is that you first interpret `row` as an x-value and then try to use that x-value as an index.

To get both the index and the value, use `enumerate()`.

Another problem is that `if row >= interval` checks that the x-value is larger than the start of the interval, but you don't check whether the x-value is smaller than the end of the interval. Therefore, your first `x_values` will get all values instead of only those belonging to the first interval.

You can use `zip` to combine the `intervals` list by itself.

Still another problem is that you keep using the same `x_values` and `y_values` to continue appending for each of the intervals.  That way `x_values` and `y_values` keep growing and growing.

Here is some example code integrating the above:

```py
import pandas as pd

x_column = 'X'
y_column = 'Y'

data = [[i*i, i] for i in range(100)]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=[x_column, y_column])

num_intervals = 10

maximum = df[x_column].max()
interval_width = maximum/num_intervals
intervals = []
for i in range(num_intervals+1):
    value = int(i * interval_width)
    intervals.append(value)

for interval_start, interval_end in zip(intervals[:-1], intervals[1:]):
    x_values = []
    y_values = []
    for row, x_val in enumerate(df[x_column]):
        if interval_start < x_val <= interval_end:
            x_values.append(x_val)
            y_values.append(df[y_column][row])
    print("interval from", interval_start, "to", interval_end, ":")
    print(" x:", x_values)
    print(" y:", y_values)
    # you probably want to store x_values and y_values belonging to the current interval
```